# Setting up a 1/2 price off formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

OK so I have an excel formula set up that is like a buy one item at full price, get the other items at 50% off.  Now, I need a formula for excel that can take two separate data sets and enter them into the buy one get one 1/2 off, and then separate them back out into their sets. This probably doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'll give an example.

```
ItemA costs 30
ItemB costs 20
ItemC costs 15
```

So first there are two sets of data:

```
Data set 1: itemAx2 and itemBx1
Data set 2: item Bx1 and itemCx1
```

So excel picks out the highest priced item of BOTH sets (itemA) and charges it at 100% of its value, then charges the rest of the items in both sets at 50% of their value.

The total charge would be: 72.50 (itemA*100%, itemA*50%, itemB*50%, item B*50%, itemC*50%)
I ALREADY HAVE A FORMULA FOR THIS FIRST STEP!

Next, I need a formula for excel to separate the charges back out so I can figure how much is charged in each set. SO.....

```
Data set 1 total charge: 55 (itemA*100%, itemA*50%, itemB*50%)
Data set 2 total charge: 17.50 (item B*50%, itemC*50%)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, please let me know if any other info is needed.

ADDITIONAL.

```
         Item.             Quantity.         Total price.         Reduced price
Set 1.   Item A.              2                   60.                 (Item A*100+itemAbc*50%)
         Item B.              1                   20                   the formula I have already
Set 2    Item B.              1.                  20                  
         Item C               1                   15
```

So I need excel to come up with one OR two formulas that figures out what is charged for set 1: 55, and set 2: 17.5

Comment: Better to show exactly how your data looks. "Data set" could be anything...

Comment: @pnuts: yes that is the same problem. I'm kinda new to the site, so didn't know you had to put. Green check mark when you have a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you use a template where you have cost and percent markdown separately. Then, take

```
 Item | Price | %Price | SellPrice(Cost x %Markdown)
 A    | 30    | 100    | 30.00
 B    | 20    | 50     | 10.00
 C    | 15    | 50     |  7.50
```

Then selectively sum by item for each set you need.

```
=ItemA_SellPrice + ItemB_Sellprice
```

and

```
=ItemB_SellPrice + ItemC_Sellprice
```

The other way to do it would be to assign your items to a data set and then filter/sum by the data set. However, you might need to create a separate Item B so that it can be uniquely inside each data set.

Comment: The data would indeed be more organised in this structure, but I think that there are some important fields (or columns) missing, namely quantity and, to make things easier, the data set. It'll then be a matter of using `SUMIF`(S)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set things where you are entering the data.

It might be simpler to use a formula that computes 50% of everything, then add back 50% of the most expensive item.

So if you have three columns: Items, Prices, Quantity. You could use a formula like:

```
=0.5*MAX(Prices)+SUMPRODUCT(Prices,Quantity)*0.5
```

If some entries in your "Quantity" column might be zero or blank, then use this formula instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(Prices*(Quantity>0))+SUMPRODUCT(Prices,Quantity))*0.5
```

For this formula to work correctly need to make sure the starting and ending row for all ranges are same.